# Raster to BufferedImage using IndexColorModel

Tags: bufferedimage, java-2d, javax.imageio, raster, color-mapping

I'm trying to present an image from a Raster with only **one band** obtained from a DICOM file using ImageIO. I don't want to read directly the buffered image using ImageIO because I need the real values from the file (the raster included in the BufferedImage obtained directly with ImageIO is always a bit different and normalized to (0-255)).

For obtaining the raster I am using the following code:

```
Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
ImageReader reader = iter.next();
DicomImageReadParam param = (DicomImageReadParam) reader.getDefaultReadParam();
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(dicomFile);
reader.setInput(iis, true);
Raster raster = reader.readRaster(0, param);
```

An then, to transform it to a BufferedImage with a custom IndexColorModel:

```
IndexColorModel colModel = grayColorModel(window, level);
BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(colModel, (WritableRaster) raster, colModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```

using the following function to build the IndexColorModel:

```
public IndexColorModel grayColorModel(int window, float level) {
    window = window;
    byte[] r = new byte[window];
    byte[] g = new byte[window];
    byte[] b = new byte[window];

    for (int i = 0; i < window; i++) {
        int val = (int) Math.round((255 - level) * 2 * i / window + 2 * level - 255);
        if (val > 255) {
            val = 255;
        }
        if (val < 0) {
            val = 0;
        }
        r[ i] = (byte) val;
        g[ i] = (byte) val;
        b[ i] = (byte) val;
    }

    return (new IndexColorModel(**NR OF BITS**, window, r, g, b));
}
```

The problem that I have is somehow related to linking the information from the raster that has only one channel to the IndexColorModel, that has 3. When I use 8 in the number of bits the data types simply don't match and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Raster ShortInterleavedRaster: width = 512 height = 512 #numDataElements 1 is incompatible with ColorModel IndexColorModel: #pixelBits = 8 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@28ec9a1a transparency = 1 transIndex   = -1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:630)
```

When I use a number bigger than 8 I don't get the error but the presented image has not the right intensities. The highest and lowest values appear simply in black.

I see that the problem is around the data types and the number of channels but I'm circling around and I'm not getting how the IndexColorModel is being used by the Raster and how do I make them compatible.

After understanding this issue I have more freedom to even create other color scales from the pixel values in the raster.

Anyone with experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: It was already solved

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it now. The only big problem is that the indexcolormodel needs to be big enough to map all values. If the raster contains some value that is bigger than the size of the mapped values arrays, the colormodel just returns 0 and instead of a white spot we have a dark spot on the image. Then you just get the max value and make the colormap big enough. I hope this prevents others from losing time with such a simple thing...

Given that, the final code for the IndexColorModel looks like this:

```
public IndexColorModel grayColorModel(int window, float level, int maxval) {
    int length = window;
    if (maxval > window) {
        length = maxval;
    }

    byte[] r = new byte[length];
    byte[] g = new byte[length];
    byte[] b = new byte[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int val = Math.round((255 / (float) window) * ((float) i - level + (float) window * 0.5f));
        if (val > 255) {
            val = 255;
        }
        if (val < 0) {
            val = 0;
        }
        r[ i] = (byte) val;
        g[ i] = (byte) val;
        b[ i] = (byte) val;
    }
    return (new IndexColorModel(16, length, r, g, b));
}
```

Comment: I guess this works, but maybe another option would be to use a gray color model?

Comment: Maybe there are other simpler ways to create customized scales, but I didn't find them. In  my case I wanted to maintain the values in the raster and just change how they are interpreted. After having this working it's easier to create new customized scales.